# After setTimeout() check if still mouse out

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of code that hides an element on mouseout.

The code looks like this:

```
var myMouseOutFunction = function (event) {

    setTimeout(function () {

    $(".classToHide").hide();

    $(".classToShow").show();

    }, 200);

};
```

This produces a result very close to what I want to do. However, I want to wait the time on the timeout (in this case 200 ms) then check to see if my mouse is still "out" of the element. If it is, I want to do .hide() and .show() on the desired elements.

I want to do this because if a user slightly mouses out then quickly mouses back in, I don't want the elements to flicker (meaning: hide then show real quick) when the user just wants to see the element.

Comment: If this question answered, please feel free to accept best suited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detailing [Kolink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12825853/297641) answer

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/EpMQ2/1/

```
var timer = null;
element.onmouseout = function () {
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
      $(".classToHide").hide();
      $(".classToShow").show();
    }, 200);
}

element.onmouseover = function () {
    clearTimeout(timer);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Assign the timeout's return value to a variable, then use `clearTimeout` in the onmouseover event.

Comment: +1. The clearTimeout bit is huge. I've started doing something similar in a Backbone application for repeat AJAX calls triggered by a setInterval. Lots of very 'bizarre' behavior before I started to clearInterval on the initial call.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` of jquery. mouseenter and mouseleave will get called only once.and use a flag if to check if `mouseenter` again called.

```
  var isMouseEnter ;
    var mouseLeaveFunction = function (event) {
       isMouseEnter = false;
        setTimeout(function () {
             if(isMouseEnter ){ return;}
             $(".classToHide").hide();

                $(".classToShow").show();

           }, 200);
    };
    var mouseEnterFunction = function(){

        isMouseEnter = true;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a boolean flag:

```
var mustWait = true;
var myMouseOutFunction = function (event) {

    setTimeout(function () {
        if(mustWait){
            mustWait = false;
        }
        else{
            $(".classToHide").hide();
            $(".classToShow").show();
            mustWait = true;
       }
    }, 200);
};
```